# Javascript History.pushState forward and backward history

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need an event for when the user clicks on the browser back and forward buttons. I have this piece of code that works, however it executes regardless of which button I click (backward & forward). How can I handle the backward and forward button clicks separately?

The code:

```
if ( window.history && window.history.pushState ) {
    window.history.pushState( 'forward', null, './#forward' );

    $( window ).on( 'popstate', function() {
        alert( 'Hello back/forward button!' );
    } );
}
```

Is it also possible to hide the `#forward` string from the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the direction:

```
$(window).on('navigate', function (event, data) {
  var direction = data.state.direction;
  if (direction == 'back') {
    // do something
  }
  if (direction == 'forward') {
    // do something else
  }
}

});
```

Comment: Hey ! Is there no "Angular way" to do this ?